# Javascript library for navigating between sections, resembling Udemy's approach

Tags: javascript, frontend

DOes anyone know a good Javascript library that resembles Udemy's approach to presenting lectures?

http://www.udemy.com/mit-600-intro-to-computer-science-programming-fall-2008/#lecture/14053

It slides up and down, with a slow animation, along a vertical line, something like a timeline. I have seen something similar, but can't remember the name. Maybe you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will suit your requirements.

[impress.js](http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/)